# New keyboard messing up mouse

Tags: keyboard, mouse, keyboard-layout

Fedora 20, xfce.

I just plugged in a new keyboard, and everything appears to work.

There's a backlight-toggling button in the corner. I press it. Now my mouse clicks don't want to register, or my mouse unclicks don't want to register, or both, or something stranger. I can't figure it out.

As soon as I unplug the keyboard and plug it back in, things are back to normal. So I fire up xev:

'd' behaves normally:

```
KeyPress event, serial 37, synthetic NO, window 0x1000001,
    root 0x290, subw 0x0, time 505354779, (-804,-173), root:(67,302),
    state 0x10, keycode 40 (keysym 0x64, d), same_screen YES,
    XLookupString gives 1 bytes: (64) "d"
    XmbLookupString gives 1 bytes: (64) "d"
    XFilterEvent returns: False

KeyRelease event, serial 37, synthetic NO, window 0x1000001,
    root 0x290, subw 0x0, time 505354867, (-804,-173), root:(67,302),
    state 0x10, keycode 40 (keysym 0x64, d), same_screen YES,
    XLookupString gives 1 bytes: (64) "d"
    XFilterEvent returns: False
```

This is what happens when I press the light-toggling button:

```
FocusOut event, serial 37, synthetic NO, window 0x1000001,
    mode NotifyNormal, detail NotifyNonlinear

VisibilityNotify event, serial 37, synthetic NO, window 0x1000001,
    state VisibilityFullyObscured
```

And then it's like the system doesn't know where my mouse is, even though it is displaying it correctly. And I can't seem to click on anything, though if after going crazy with the mouse I do apparently click on something, it doesn't seem to want me to unclick.

As an example, I was getting a lot of these:

```
MotionNotify event, serial 37, synthetic NO, window 0x1000001,
    root 0x290, subw 0x0, time 505483157, (565,160), root:(1436,635),
    state 0x210, is_hint 0, same_screen YES
```

Even when my mouse wasn't anywhere near the input detector window.

Any tips? I'm a little lost here, and Google isn't finding my anything.

Comment: More information about the keyboard could help. You can use `lsusb -v` and `dmesg` to see the interfaces it has, what modules are used for them. If it's a "gaming" keyboard, I'm thinking it could have an extra interface to send configuration info that is mistaken for a mouse/joystick/other input. You can use `xinput` to see if it shows up as an extra mouse for instance. And disable it with `xinput --disable <id>` to test.

Comment: Thank you! `xinput --disable x; sleep 10; xinput --enable x` (so I could test the results and still get my keyboard back!) worked great. Now I need to see if I can re-enable those buttons and customize how they work. For instance, three of them are simply volume control.